# code igniter HMVC + REST setup

Tags: php, rest, codeigniter-3, codeigniter-hmvc

i have already set up a HMVC (i learned my setup from https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCkzjsv1ymTmdGpWTtZ7nM5A/videos ) and using it on my program. but i need it to re-code it into a RESTful type.

i have a `MY_Controller.php` file

```
<?php

class MY_Controller extends MX_Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->module('Templates');
        $this->load->module('Login');

    }

}

?>
```

this file is for loading modules easily. now i try to set up my REST_Controller etc. i have a folder like this

```
application
- - modules
- - - - Rest
- - - - - - controller
- - - - - - - Api.php
- - - - - - libraries
- - - - - - - Rest_Controller.php
- - - - - - - Format.php
- - - - - - config
- - - - - - - rest.php
- - - - - - models
- - - - - - views
```

i edited my `REST_Controller.php` from

```
abstract class REST_Controller extends CI_Controller {
```

into

```
abstract class REST_Controller extends MY_Controller {
```

and my `Api.php` is,

```
<?php 
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

require APPPATH.'modules/Rest/libraries/REST_Controller.php';

class Api extends REST_Controller {
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function student_get(){
        $this->response('My first API response');
    }
}
```

but when i do `http://localhost/FOLDERNAME/Api/student_get` on my browser

i got an error

```
404 Page Not Found

The page you requested was not found.
```

also i found this REST on mvc tutorial, it says that if i go to http://myapi.com/ it should open your codeigniter page, and it is good. but i only got

```
Buy this domain
The domain myapi.com may be for sale by its owner! etc.
```

i use `Phil Sturgeon's REST Library` by the way

im still not sure if what im doing is right. can someone please tell me what the error is or how i can do it correctly. thanks

Comment: Have you tried to place `Format` and `REST_Controller` into `APPPATH.'libraries'` directory and call those like that?

Comment: not yet. if ever i placed it like that, how can i check if its working

Comment: still shows 404 page not found when i do `http://localhost/FOLDERNAME/Api/student_get` on my browser

Comment: Try if `http://localhost/FOLDERNAME/index.php/Api/student_get` working.

Comment: still page not found @Tpojka

Comment: If you exclude REST library, can you reach that page?

Comment: i have errors. my folder name and controller name are different. now that they are same i got this error `Unable to load the requested language file: language/english/rest_controller_lang.php`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36742885/codeigniter-hmvc-rest-unable-to-load-the-requested-language-file-language-engli

Comment: Put all `REST` files out of modules and place thse in coresponding locations in `APPPATH`.

Comment: i already did it. it has the same error

Comment: I suggest to make over and follow video again. It is hard to say what is wrong if video series are functional and your code is not.

Comment: no. its not wrong. the problem is it is a setup for mvc(the video) and mine is for hmvc